# Loading data from Excel into a class

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a class in VBA with several private variables

```
Private pVar1 as Double
Private pVar2 as Double
...
```

I have one pair of `Property Get/Let` for each variable.

In Excel, I have a series labels (in column A) and values (in column B), each matching one variable. What's the best way to read this data from Excel to VBA?

I looked at this http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2011/12/26/populating-class-properties/ but it's not entirely appropriate in this situation.

Is my only solution to use

```
Dim obj as new myClass
obj.property1 = range("b1").value
obj.property2 = range("b2").value
...
```

or is there as way to choose which `obj.property` I assign a value to, based on `range("a1").value`?

Comment: How would the code determine which property to use? If A1 contains the property name, you can use CallByName: `callbyname obj, Range("A1").Value, VbLet, Range("B1").value` for instance.

Comment: I'll have to investigate this CallByName - never heard of this before!

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was after. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1 contains the property name, you can use CallByName:

```
callbyname obj, Range("A1").Value, VbLet, Range("B1").value
```

for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your link covers the " map column positions to properties" quite well.  You could:

```
For iRow = lo to hi
  propname = ws.cells(iRow, 1)
  Select Case propname
  Case "alpha": obj.Alpha = ws.cells(iRow, 2)
  ..
  Case Else: Msgbox "Oops"
  End Select
Next iRow
```

Comment: This is a really good approach and probably "better" from a robust code point of view. Could add constants too instead of hard coding text. I will definitely use this approach for some future work, but for my current project the other answer was better. Thanks though!